# Find the least $N$ so there is no square

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> Find the least positive integer $N$ such that the set of $1000$ consecutive integers beginning with $1000 \cdot N$ contains no square of an integer.

Let $x^2$ appear before $1000N$ so:

$(x+1)^2 - x^2 > 1000 \implies x \ge 500$

Let $A = [1000N, 1000(N+1)]$

So I let $x=500$ then, $x^2 = 250000$, obviously this is impossible since the set has a square already.

So now I need to set some number, $k^2 \ge 501^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{1000}$

So I need to solve the quadratic residue:

$k^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{1000}$ with constraints for $k$.

Lets see: $500^2 = 250000$ and $501^2 = 251001$ and $502^2 = 252004$

$501^2 = 500^2 + 1000 + \sum_{k=1}^{1} 2k - 1$

$502^2 = 500^2 + 2(1000) + \sum_{k=1}^{2} 2k - 1$

The next $n$th square after $500$ is generalized:

$p = 500^2 + n(1000) + \sum_{k=1}^{n} 2k - 1$

Take $p \pmod{1000}$

$p \equiv n + \sum_{k=1}^{n} 2k - 1 \pmod{1000}$

$p \equiv n + n^2 \pmod{1000}$

$n(n+1) \equiv 0 \pmod{1000}$

$n \equiv 0$ and $n \equiv -1 \pmod{1000}$

But this method doesnt work properly. The final answer is: $N = 282$.

**Please some hints only.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT :

As you wrote, we have $x\ge 500$.

Observe that 
$$501^2=251001,\quad 502^2=252004,\quad 503^2=253009,\cdots$$
$$251\times 1000=251000,\quad 252\times 1000=252000,\quad 253\times 1000=253000,\cdots$$

Now we need to have
$$(500+a)^2-(250+a)\times 1000\gt 1000\Rightarrow  a\gt 31$$
where $N=250+a$.

Answer (score 0):

To have $(500+a)^2<1000N$ and $(500+a+1)^2\ge 1000(N+1)$ we need
$$500^2+1000a+a^2<1000N,\qquad 500^2+1000(a+1)+(a+1)^2\ge 1000(N+1) $$
and hence 
$$ 250 +a+1+\left\lfloor\frac{(a+1)^2}{1000}\right\rfloor\ge N +1>N>250+a+\left\lfloor\frac {a^2}{1000}\right\rfloor$$
Therefore look for small $a$ with $\left\lfloor\frac{(a+1)^2}{1000}\right\rfloor>\left\lfloor\frac {\strut a^2}{1000}\right\rfloor$.